# How to find the column data object name that includes column members

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am trying to insert a record using Link to SQL. I know I need to create a new object that includes the column data to be submitted. But How do I identify that object name?

I am successfully able to delete the record, but not able to insert record as I am not able to create a new "student" object

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Student.Models;

namespace Student.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Student/

        private IStudentRepository  _repository;

        public StudentController() : this(new StudentRepository())
        {
        }

        public StudentController(IStudentRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {    
             return View(_repository.ListAll());
        }


        public ActionResult RemoveStudent(int id)
        {

            StudentDataContext student= new StudentDataContext();

            var std = student.Students.Single(h => h.StudentID == id);
            student.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(std);
            student.SubmitChanges();
            return Content("Student " + id + " Removed");
        }

        public ActionResult AddStudent(int studentID)
        {
            StudentDataContext student= new StudentDataContext();

            var std = student.Students.FirstOrDefault(h => h.StudentID == studentID);

            if (std == null || std.StudentID < 1)
            {

            student.Students.InsertOnSubmit(std);
            student.SubmitChanges();
            return Content("Student " + id + " Added");

            }

            return Content("Student  " + studentID + " is already present");
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `new Student()` - or whatever the name of your object is.

```
if (std == null || std.StudentID < 1)
{
    // create a new student before trying to insert
    std = new Student() { StudentID = id };

    student.Students.InsertOnSubmit(std);
    student.SubmitChanges();
    return Content("Student " + id + " Added");
}
```

From my reading your question is

> But How do I identify that object name?

i.e. "what is the name of the class?"

You can see this on the LINQ-to-SQL designer. The name of the class is the same as the name of the object on the designer which describes the table. The *default* name for the class is the same as the table - but if it clashes with another class of that name, then it will be renamed to `Student1`.

Comment: I added an index view which lists all the students. I want to list all those students in descending order. How do I do that?